# Getting number of user ratings for all apps on App Store

Tags: ios, app-store, itunes-store

I've been approved for using EPF(Enterprise Partner Feed) to download metadata of App Store. However, I want to get the number of user ratings for all apps and this information is not included in EPF data.

The current solution is using iTunes Search API (https://itunes.apple.com/lookup?id=909253) but there are around 1 million apps. Sending 1M requests per day to this API seems to be a huge load to both sides.

Answer (score 2):

```
https://itunes.apple.com/lookup?id=909253,284882215
```

iTunes Search API could take up to 200 ids per request, just concatenate them with comma.

By sending 200 ids per request, I need only 5000 requests to query all apps. It won't be a problem to my server as well as to Apple server(would not be banned).